# How to use QT Designer on python to auto show file without choose itu directly

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I make one widget to show image. but I have to choose it manually by selecting the location of the folder and selecting the image.

I use this code for button

```
btnImage = QPushButton("Load an image")
btnImage.clicked.connect(self.pickFile)
button_layout.addWidget(btnImage)
```

pickFile is process to search image that i want to show, and this for pickFile to show image

```
def pickFile(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')
    pixmap = self.resizeImage(filename[0])
    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

how do i make it when i click the button the widget automatically displays the image in the folder that i specify without having to manually select it in the displayed box?

because the folder contains only one image,

however, the picture will always change with a different name

but I have to choose it manually by selecting the location of the folder and selecting the image and it wasting time.

Comment: 1) If you don't want the user to select the image, then why do you use QFileDialog? 2) Are there other files or folders in that folder, does the image have a specific extension (*.png, *.jpg, etc)?

Comment: ((1)) I just looking framework that can build UI in python. so i meet qt designer and i looking how to show image and i found QFileDIalog. So what should I use?......
((2.)) there is only one picture that will always change. the file extension used is .jpg